# How to set and get datatable from Redis Cache?

Tags: c#, redis, datatable, dataset, stackexchange.redis

I have implemented Client-Side Caching using Redis in a .Net Winforms Application.
I want to reduce the time to fetch the data from redis server. How can I improve the cache invalidation and storing process to effectively improve the GET process from the redis server?

```
public void SaveDataTableInMemoryCache(string key, DataSet dataset)
    {
        var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
        IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
        string jsonDataSet = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataset);
        db.StringSet(key, jsonDataSet, TimeSpan.FromHours(10));
    }


public DataSet RetrieveDataTableFromCache(string key)
    {
        var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
        IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
        string cachedJsonDataSet = db.StringGet(key);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cachedJsonDataSet))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(cachedJsonDataSet);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Currently I am serializing the dataset to JSON and storing into Redis using Key-Value method.
And getting data from JSON and deserializing back to dataset and bind to a data grid in the winforms application.

**To fetch 100,000 records. The server takes 5 - 8 seconds. I want it to reduce to less than a second or to the minimum time possible.**

What improvements can be made to this getting and setting architecture?

Comment: Why in the world would you cache _the whole dataset_ (with ~100k rows) in contrast to individual rows?

Comment: User wants to see the complete dataset on his screen in one go. I am new to caching and  redis. If there are some resources which can help, please refer. @Fildor

Comment: And I want to fetch the complete dataset every time.

Comment: First of all: That requirement is ridiculous. He clearly does _not_ want that because that is impossible with 100k records. User needs thorough consulting. 2nd: That requirement is completely unrelated to how you organize your cache.

Comment: _"And I want to fetch the complete dataset every time."_ - OK. Done. You are out of options. Outside getting faster server, network equipment and workstations.

Comment: The user is seeing the PnL data in the pivot grid which is a consolidated grid. Then he can add drag and drop any column of the choice. So I am loading all the data at once and showing him the results. @Fildor

Comment: As I said: Live with the delay. You can only change to faster copper.

Comment: What user can look at 100k rows at the same time? This makes no sense. Caching is not the problem here and won't improve performance because the dataset is simply too huge. Have you thought about paging?

Comment: The user is not looking at 100k rows. It is financial data. User is checking the total of the all the rows which is calculated automatically based on the filters. There are various filters which can be applied and the combination can be huge. So we fill all the data at once and then the filters work without any delay and the user can look at whichever trade/strategy/and so on.. as he wants to. @GoodNightNerdPride

Comment: So the rows are never displayed? Only the total? Why not send all the filters to the DB and calculate the totals there?